# How can I set a Django GenericForeignKey pointing to multiple classes on ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, generic-foreign-key

Still a newbie, I have to adapt a Django (v1.10) script. The original script uses a main class "initiative" which can have any number of "supporters".

The adaptions I have to make include having another main class called "policy" along "initiative" (similar behaviours, different fields). I'm stuck with a ManyToManyField on "initiative" and "policy" which should point to Supporters where I'm trying to use a GenericRelation to support both main classes. I get the following error message:

```
initproc.Supporter: (fields.E336) The model is used as an intermediate model by 'initproc.Initiative.supporters', but it does not have a foreign key to 'Initiative' or 'User'.
initproc.Supporter: (fields.E336) The model is used as an intermediate model by 'initproc.Policy.supporters', but it does not have a foreign key to 'Policy' or 'User'.
```

My `models.py` (removed everything irrelevant) BEFORE:

```
# ------------------------------ Initiative ------------------------------------
class Initiative(models.Model):

  supporters = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Supporter")


# ------------------------------- Supporter -------------.----------------------
class Supporter(models.Model):

  class Meta:
    unique_together = (("user", "initiative"),)

  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  initiative = models.ForeignKey(Initiative, related_name="supporting")
```

and AFTER my modifications:

```
# ------------------------------- Supporter ------------------------------------
class Supporter(models.Model):

  class Meta:
    unique_together = (("user", "target_type", "target_id"),)

  user = models.ForeignKey(User)

  target_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  target_id = models.IntegerField()
  target = GenericForeignKey('target_type', 'target_id')

# -------------------------------- Policy --------------------------------------
class Policy(PolicyBase):

  supporters = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Supporter")

# ------------------------------ Initiative ------------------------------------
class Initiative(models.Model):

  supporters = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Supporter")
```

which throws the above error. I think I understand the issue is not the ForeignKey to User (hasn't changed) but my attempt to make Supporter work for both Initiative and Policy. I could only find `through_fields` looking for a fix but I think I'm also looking at the wrong place.

Question:
How can I set a GenericForeignKey pointing to multiple classes on ManyToManyField? I'd also like to know where I have to put the related_name parameter now.

Comment: You can make an intermediate model, that refers to a `Supporter`, and has a `GenericForeignKey` to refer to "something else" (well a `ManyToManyField` basically has a hidden table as well, but wit two `ForeignKey`s), but it look like "weird modeling" to do this.

Comment: It feels weird as it is already, so you say Policy/Initiative=> intermediate => Supporter?

Comment: That being said, I wonder if two `ManyToManyField`s (one to `Policy` and one to `Initiative`) will not provide more "contracts".

Comment: yeah, but a `ManyToMany` does the same, except that it "hides" the `intermediate`.

Comment: ok, let me try two ManyToManyFields if I can get at least the errors to stop